# how to reuse a hierarchy of Objects with some changes

Tags: oop

I've been using a hierarchy of objects as input of one of my rest API's which devekoped using Java. like this, a street including some houses; each house contains some room:

```
{"streetName":"street1","houses":[{"number":22,"rooms":[{"roomId":1,"roomWidth":6}]}]}
```

in another rest i need the exact same hierarchy with most of the fields but i need some more fields for room entity (the last object at hierarchy tree). I don't like the idea of just adding extra fields to original Room class cause they are not used in first Rest API. Just copy/pasting the whole hierarchy classes in new classes for the new Rest API is another bad idea. Currently i've done this:

```
public class StreetForRest2 extends StreetForRest1 {
@Override
public void setHouseForRest1(HouseForRest1 houseForRest1){
     //cast and set HouseForRest2  }
//the same for getter
}

public class HouseForRest2 extends HouseForRest1 {//same as above}

public class RoomForRest2 extends RoomForRest1 {
//extra fields with setters and getters
}
```

But still not satisfied with it. Any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you use Jackson's ObjectMapper or Gson or something similar to serialize your POJOs in a json format. I would suggest to use a Json object (it's like a HashMap, all such libraries have one, like Jackson's JsonNode) and not POJOs for such cases so that you can handle them in a more flexible way. Doing so, you can use then the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to add extra functionality in an OOP style without modifying your original object.

For example let's assume and you want to add some extra properties to houses that are flagged as featured in your database. You can do something like this:

```
public interface Jsonable {
    JsonNode asJson();
}

public class SimpleStreetJson implements Jsonable {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final HouseForRest1 pojo;

    public SimpleStreetJson(ObjectMapper objectMapper, HouseForRest1 pojo) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.pojo = pojo;
    }

    public JsonNode asJson() {
        return objectMapper.convertValue(pojo, JsonNode.class);
    }
}

public class JsonWithFeatureHouses implements Jsonable {
    private final Jsonable jsonable;
    private final Collection<String> featuredHousesIds;

    public JsonWithFeatureHouses(Jsonable jsonable, Collection<String> featuredHousesIds) {
        this.jsonable = jsonable;
        this.featuredHousesIds = featuredHousesIds;
    }

    public JsonNode asJson() {
        JsonNode json = jsonable.asJson();
        for(house : jsonable.asJson().get("houses")) {
            if(featuredHousesIds.contains(house.get("id"))) {
                house.put("featured", true);
                house.put("featured_house_url", "url here ...")
            }
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

Finally, you can construct you objects like this:

```
Json json = new JsonWithFeatureHouses(new SimpleStreetJson(objectMapper, pojo)).asJson();
```